# Is the solution of SVM classifier a vector in second conjugate space of the RKHS

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Let the training points be given by $x_1, x_2 \cdots x_m$. Suppose we want to predict the class of a new point $x$ as $f(x)$. In an linear SVM this is a dot product usually denoted by $<w,x>$ where $w$ is the separating plane.

Can we call this solution $F_x(f_w)=f_w(x)=<w,x>$, where $w$ and $x$ both reside in hilbert space. $w$ can be said to exist in space spanned by training vectors as it is a linear combination of training vectors.

Is this reasoning correct? If not please help me through the correct interpretation

Answer (score 1):

Almost. In kernel SVM, the hyperplane $\mathbf{w}$ exists only in feature space. What is being calculated is the inner product *in feature space*, i.e.:
$$\langle \mathbf{w}, \varphi(\mathbf{x})\rangle,$$
where $\varphi(\cdot)$ is the (possibly unknown) embedding function from input space to feature space.

In terms of kernel evaluations with kernel function $\kappa(\cdot,\cdot)$, this becomes:
$$\langle \mathbf{w}, \varphi(\mathbf{x})\rangle = \sum_{i\in SV} \alpha_i y_i \kappa(\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}),$$
with $\alpha$ the support values and $y$ the vector of labels.

Comment: Actually this doubt occurred to me while reading about kernel SVM but have discussed linear SVM for simplicity.